# How to know if node is installed with homebrew or nvm?

Tags: node.js, homebrew, nvm

I had installed & uninstalled `node` on Mac OS with multiple ways using `homebrew`, `nvm` etc

Now I don't remember which technique I had used last time to install.

Is there a way to find our how node was installed or which tool is used to install node ?

Comment: `nvm ls` should give you any installed node versions through nvm. if not, then you have directly installed node

Answer (score 6):

To check installed packages with **brew** you can try

```
brew deps --tree --installed
```

Then you can search for your package to check if installed by **brew** or not.
[image]